# Laravel 5 authentication middleware always redirects to root or login

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-5

When I protect routes in Laravel 5 it works well when I'm not logged in because it redirects the protected routes to the login page but once I login and try to access the protected routes it redirects me to the root route.
For example if I try to access /people or /people/1 it will redirect me to /

Here's my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
 Route::resource('people', 'PeopleController');
 Route::resource('people.checkins', 'CheckinsController');
 Route::model('checkins', 'Checkin');
 Route::model('people', 'Person');

 Route::bind('checkins', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Checkin::whereId($value)->first();
 });
 Route::bind('people', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Person::whereId($value)->first();
 });
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
 Route::auth();

 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Comment: is this on Laravel 5.2?

Comment: Yes, Laravel 5.2.5 @lagbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to be using Auth you should have the 'web' group applied to those routes as well.

You can adjust your route group that is using the 'auth' middleware to:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    // ...
});
```

**UPDATE** For Laravel 5.2.27. If you have installed a fresh copy of laravel/laravel >= 5.2.27 Your routes will be wrapped in a group that applies the 'web' middleware by default now. This is only for fresh installs as this change is to App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider which an upgrade to laravel/framework will not touch.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP, I updated the App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider but still I cannot get past my login page. I'm just redirected every time I try to access any protected routes. Any other suggestions, I've been stuck on this for days now.