# When using auth middleware, its redirecting me to home page

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am new in laravel app development. When I am using `auth` `middleware`, then it works fine for unregistered user(redirecting to login page). But when **logged user** going to visit that page, then its redirecting to home page (root directory).

below the route from routes.php code is

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('/edit', 'userController@edit');
});
```

Below my userController.php code is

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\allUsers;
 class userController extends Controller
 {
     public function index(){
     }

     public function show($id){
     }

     public function edit(){
         return view('auth.user_edit');
     }
  }
```

Below my authController code is

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use App\User;
 use Validator;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
 {
 /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration & Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
| authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
| a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
|
*/

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

Anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the $redirectTo variable in your AuthController:

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

**Update:**

Try Changing your route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('edit', 'userController@edit');
});
```

Route::resource creates all CRUD routes for your automatically.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Can you post your Auth Controller in the question

Comment: Please check  now. Updated!!

Comment: maximl337, have a look on my answer. Problem solved. I got that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553345/laravel-5-authentication-middleware-always-redirects-to-root-or-login

Answer (score 0):

Yes Problem solved. Just changed the route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
     Route::get('/edit', 'userController@edit');
});
```